# Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given

Tags: php, mysqli

When trying to connect to my DB in localhost I receive these errors:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\A-14\01.php on line 10

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\A-14\01.php on line 10

And these are connection steps, it's get problematic in the second step when I put my DB's name in:

```
$dblink = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') || die(mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_select_db($dblink , "tst") or die(mysqli_error($dblink));

mysqli_query($dblink , "SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
```

What should I do?

Comment: Kindly, share the php code that you have done so far

Comment: Remove `|| die(mysqli_connect_error())`

Comment: PHP manual doesn't bite: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: Thank evryone the answer was writng: 'or' istet of '||' in first line                                        $dblink = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') || die(mysqli_connect_error());